# Android Background Service With Job Scheduler For Notification

Tags: service, android-notifications, job-scheduling, android-jobscheduler

I am Using Job Scheduler for android notification. My Code is Work fine. But Some Times I Got a Notification Twice. But I Given One Minute Interval For Service Run.
What Will I Do The Service Work Correctly?

This is My Job Scheduler Code to Start Service And I am Using Service Only.

JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
                ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),NotifyService.class);

```
            JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(15,componentName)
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                    .setPeriodic(60000)
                    .setPersisted(true)
                    .build();

            jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a late post, but you can use WorkManager in Android to setup a Periodic Work Request.

I've been using WorkManager, and it seems to be working reliably.

You can read up more on other work primitives to suit your task [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/threading), but the below implementation uses Worker for threading in WorkManager, which performs work synchronously on a background thread.

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends Worker {

    public BackgroundWorker
            (@NonNull Context context,
             @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
             super(context, params);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Worker.Result doWork() {     
        yourBackgroundTask();  // yourBackgroundTask() implementation
        return Result.success();
    }

    public static void schedulePeriodicWork(Data data) {
        // When multiple constraints are specified like below, 
        // your task will run only when all the constraints are met.
        Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                        .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
                        .setRequiresCharging(true)
                        .build();

        PeriodicWorkRequest taskWork = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(BackgroundWorker.class, 60,
                TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .setInputData(data)
                .build();

        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(taskWork);
    } 
}
```

Later in your MainActivity file, inside `onCreate()`:

```
Data data = workData();

BackgroundWorker.schedulePeriodicWork(data);
```

Then outside the `onCreate()` method,

```
private Data workData() {
    return new Data.Builder() // to build Data objects
        .build();
}
```

One small thing to note, is that though we set the above task to execute every 60 minutes, each iteration may not be executed at the same time interval.

According to Android documentation, WorkManager is meant for deferrable work, and some drift must be tolerated. However, you can check your log console for the update, "`WM-WorkerWrapper: Worker result SUCCESS for Work`".

Hope this is helpful.